# Intel(R) Linux(TM) Graphics Driver Error after inserting password

Tags: drivers, video, intel

I download [Intel(R) Linux(TM) Graphics Driver](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) for Ubuntu 13.04 x64 because I am using Ubuntu 13.04 x64, after I install it with `dpkg`, Program is fully installed, I start it and I can choose of `Close` or `Next`, I click on `Next` and all test are passing ok.

```
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... OK
Checking kernel version... OK
Checking available repositories... OK
```

Now I can choose of `Back`, `Close` and `Install`, I click on `Install`, After the program work some time,It ask me of system administrator password, I type it and press `Enter`, the password is accepted, the program is running some time and generate 2 error windows:

text of first window : `Error running transaction: GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-no-package: Package i915-3.9-3.8-dkms isn't available`

text of second window : `Package i915-3.9-3.8-dkms isn't available`

In the main window is write

```
Setting up repositories... OK
Installing packages...
    Updating package cache...
    Installing packages... Failed
```

Because it doesn't work?

(Now I can't make screenshot, the generated image is a simple gray background)

Answer (score 0):

The package is listed here:

https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/13.04/main/dists/Ubuntu/13.04/binary-amd64/Packages

You can try manually installing the package and re-run the installer.

If that fails, post the error message here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/164